# mesh package in R

Tags: r, rcpp, cgal, point-cloud-library, lidar

I am looking for an `R` package which could provide a framework to interact with
Airborne-Laster-Scanning (ALS)-data and polygon-meshes. I guess it is pretty
straightforward to use `RCPP` for interfacing:

### Libraries

- [OpenMesh](http://www.openmesh.org/)
- [libLas](http://www.liblas.org/)
- [Pointclouds](http://www.pointclouds.org/)
- [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/)
- [meshlab](http://meshlab.sourceforge.net/)

### Requested Features

To name a few:

- Mesh-Lidar-interaction

  - refine/coarse triangulated mesh according to ALS
  - interpolate elevation from ALS
- Inject points/lines/holes into the mesh
- Mesh-Simplification
- Reading and writing in different mesh-formats (`.stl,.2dm`, ...)

P.S.: I would also be interested in implementations  in `julia` or `haskell`.

Comment: Have you checked the Lastools packages ?
http://www.cs.unc.edu/~isenburg/lastools/